# Signs for the trustworthiness of the SundaeSwap project?

Tags: security

I would like to know, what are known signs about the trustworthiness of the project SudaeSwap?

What could be technically achievable black swan scenarios?

Is it a project that is connected with Cardano?

Comment: This question seems to be opinion based, which may cause it to be closed. For instance, in my opinion Sundaeswap is a trustworthy project but not everyone shares this opinion. I would recommend changing your question.

Comment: It's a bit fishy the whole 'come stake at our pool with 100% fees and then we'll give you tokens when we launch', what's to stop them from disappearing and not releasing anything while keeping all the ADA rewards minted all that time?

Comment: Opinion based questions are better asked in Reddit's Cardano subreddit

Answer (score 5):

As much as I'm voting to close this question as it is opinion based, I'm going to provide my insight as it can save people money.

For me, they are not trustworthy because:

- The initial team and most of the team is anonymous
- They have no track record of previous projects
- They have a plan to take millions of dollars from the community but they do not have a value-offering by having at least a whitepaper. Several dates promising the whitepaper has been posted but later deleted by the team
- They are banning people raising concerns from their twitter and discord, censoring discussion
- They have no skills to even run their own pool and are trying to outsource it, which is a basic technical skill when you try to build on Cardano

Several highly trusted community members have already warned about the red flags, for example [Sebastien](https://twitter.com/SebastienGllmt/status/1396492945033883651).

Answer (score 1):

Charles Hoskinson has posted on Twitter that he has a meeting with SundaeSwap's team sometime soon and will advise on his feedback about the project. It is not clear when the meeting will take place but my best guess is that it will be within the next 30 days.